# static Finder from parent class

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm annoyed of adding static Finders to all my Model classes.

Why isn't it possible to do this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class MyModel<T> extends Model {

    public static Finder<Integer,T> FIND = new Finder<Integer, T>(Integer.class,T.class);

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class ValidationScript extends MyModel<ValidationScript> {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @Column(length = 5000)
    public String scriptCode;

}
```

Comment: Not a solution, just tip: most IDE's allows now to create some kind of dynamic templates of code, I added one in Idea and it creates proper finder at the single keyboard shortcut press.

Comment: Can I ask you to post your live templete for Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is quite easy. Use this template instead manual adding `@Id` field and `Finder`

```
@javax.persistence.Id
public $ID$ id;

public static Finder<$ID$, $CL$> find
        = new Finder<$ID$, $CL$>($ID$.class, $CL$.class);
```

After paste it in template's editor click `Edit variables` and set expression for `CL` to `className()`

take a look at the screenshots

[image: live template for Finder]

[image: live template variables]

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time to search a solution because I have the same problem but this is not a problem related to Play/Ebean.

Unfortunately you can not do this in Java. By design, a static field is shared by all suclasses (the same object!). And of course you cannot have an object with multiple types!
The generics are used at compile time to check the correctness of the methods invocation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

The solution you proposed with the use of generics cannot work because the static field/method cannot access the type (all instance may have a different type).

In your case the field *FIND* is shared for all the subclasses of *MyModel*.

---

I tried to convert you field in a static method finder() and to create a "finder pool" with a static hashmap class/finder but you must anyway provide the class like this  MyModel.finder(ValidationScript.class) because the invoker is always the superclass.

Too much verbose...

Comment: Thx for the analysis. It's indeed not a problem of Play, I was just curious about the practice of other Play developers. biesior's suggestion looks really nice here.